# how to use the in_array function, that is storing a variable from an input field

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a value already exists in an array with the in_array function but it is not working. When i assign the $companyalis variable to a string, lets say "Bay" it works. Please how can i solve this issue. Note: the $alias contains a value from an input field.

```
 $companyalis = strtoupper($alias);
    if (is_array($responses)) {
        $data = [];
        foreach ($responses as $val) {
            $data[] = $val['alias'];
        }

        if (in_array($companyalis, $data)) {
            echo "Alias is already defined";
        }else {
            echo "Alias does not exist";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever see either of those echo statements? Where is it going wrong exactly?

Comment: If `$companyalis = 'Bay'` works but `$companyalis = strtoupper($alias)` doesn't, then I guess `$responses` contains `Bay` but not `BAY`. Why don't you just inspect it and see what's inside?

Comment: maybe `ucfirst` and not `strtoupper`

Comment: A question and several answers but.... No news from John....?

Answer (score 0):

```
$aliasList[] = "Other";
$aliasList[] = "manY";
$aliasList[] = "someTime";

$test = "Many";

if(in_array(strtolower($test),array_map('strtolower',$aliasList)))  echo "Find";
else echo "Not Find";
```

I think this code can help you if I understood your question correctly.

The principle is to pass the search string in lowercase as well as all the elements of the array. Via the "strtolower" function applied thanks to "array_map" (thus on the whole array)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly

```
$companyalis = strtoupper($alias);
if (is_array($responses)) {
      $data = [];
      foreach ($responses as $val) {
            $data[] = $val['alias'];
      }

      if (in_array($companyalis, array_values($data))) {
            echo "Alias is already defined";
      } else {
            echo "Alias does not exist";
      }
}
```